# CBCentral vs CBCentralManager

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbcentralmanager

What is a difference between them? When should I use *CBCentral* and when *CBCentralManager*?

As I understood, Both CBCentralManager and CBCentral are used to manage connections, but CBCentral allows mobile app to acts as another BLE device, am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you're not.

`CBCentral` is a model object representing a separate device, to which your app is acting as a peripheral - in which case you'd have a running `CBPeripheralManager` object to drive this.

`CBCentralManager` is when your app (and therefore your device) is acting as a central, and is looking for peripherals - these will be modelled in your app as `CBPeripheral` objects.

So in summary - the `...Manager` objects are what your app is *doing* (is it a Central, or a Peripheral?).

The `CBCentral` and `CBPeripheral` objects represent *other things* that your app is connected to.